# Specify platform during package install

Tags: python, conda

Some packages in Conda include both platform-specific (e.g., **osx-64**) and platform-agnostic (**noarch**) builds. While one can easily specify a channel using either the `--channel` flag or with `CHANNEL::PACKAGE` syntax, there isn't any documentation on specifying platform.

When I run `conda info`, I can see that in each channel I have added in my configuration, there is a URL for both **osx-64** and **noarch**. I can set priority for channels, but I don't see any equivalent option for platform.

As a manual workaround, I realize I can directly install from a channel's tarball. For example, if I wanted the **noarch** version of Automat from Conda Forge, I could run

```
conda install https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/automat/0.7.0/download/noarch/automat-0.7.0-py_1.tar.bz2
```

or for **osx-64**

```
conda install https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/automat/0.7.0/download/osx-64/automat-0.7.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
```

but this doesn't install dependencies, so one must subsequently run

```
conda upgrade automat
```

**How can one directly indicate to use a specific platform when installing a package?**

Comment: I don't understand how a package can be both noarch (that is, not reliant on any architecture) and simultaneously depend on a particular architecture. Does the noarch version not include a C-extension? It seems like these packages should have different names, or perhaps use a "feature" (although I think those are deprecated) similar to the openblas vs. mkl split.

Comment: @darthbith In the case of Automat, looks like it's an historical artifact, i.e., only in their last commit did they convert to `noarch` ([see feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/automat-feedstock)). Previously, they were generating tarballs that (at least for osx-64) had precompiled binaries included. TBH, I'm not really interested in doing this practically, but it sort of came up in a different question and I was puzzling over whether one can specify platform in `conda install` when the version is identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you view your channel URLs using `conda info`, e.g.,

```
channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-64
               https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
               https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
               https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
```

you can use the subdirectories to specify the platform-specific channels using the `CHANNEL::PACKAGE` syntax.

For example, in the Conda Forge case, one would use either

```
conda install conda-forge/osx-64::automat
```

or

```
conda install conda-forge/noarch::automat
```