# Selenium TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'

Tags: python, selenium, typeerror, selenium4, selenium3

I'm refactoring my app from procedural code to OOP. I am trying to do this Driver class.

UPDATE: this works in Windows but not in Mac.

```
# IMPORTS
from sys import platform
import os
from os import system

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# import Action chains 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

class Driver():
    def __init__(self):
        #set executable path to driver
        self.dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        if platform == "win32":
            self.executable_path = os.path.join(self.dirname, 'geckodriver.exe') #must save the gecko file to same directory where python is. path to geckodriver (firefox drive/motor) on your machine
            print("Gecko (Firefox) filepath is: ", self.executable_path)
        if platform == "darwin":
            self.executable_path = os.path.join(self.dirname, 'geckodriver') #must save the gecko file to same directory where python is. path to geckodriver (firefox drive/motor) on your machine
            print("Gecko (Firefox) filepath is: ", self.executable_path)
            
        self.service = Service(self.executable_path) 
            
        self.opts = FirefoxOptions()
        #self.opts.add_argument(f"--width={int(screen_width/4)}")
        #self.opts.add_argument(f"--height={int(screen_height/2)}")

        self.driver = Firefox(service=self.service, options=self.opts)
        
        self.driver.set_window_position(-10, 0)
        
        self.driver.get("https://google.com/")
    
Driver()
```

This will give me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/driverClass.py", line 72, in <module>
    Driver()
  File "/driverClass.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.driver = Firefox(service=self.service, options=self.opts)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

Why is this? I'm refactoring my code to OOP. The code worked before when using procedural code.

This is from the working code:

```
# driver configs
service = Service(executable_path) #pass in path to geckodriver
opts = FirefoxOptions()
#opts.add_argument(f"--width={int(screen_width/4)}")
#opts.add_argument(f"--height={int(screen_height/2)}")
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=opts)

driver.set_window_position(-10, 0)
#driver.set_window_size(int(screen_width/4), int(screen_height))

driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Comment: Provide full stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

...implies that *`service`* is an unexpected keyword argument.

The possible reason, you are still using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) **v3.x** and the *keyword argument* *`service`*
wasn't supported.

---

### Solution

Since [Selenium 4.0 Beta 1](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/11f7dde1663513866c4e0836692129f947bd3631/py/CHANGES#L116):

> Deprecate all but `Options` and `Service` arguments in driver instantiation. (#9125,#9128)

So you need to upgrade to ***Selenium 4.x***

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service' error using Python Selenium ChromeDriver with company pac file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70537951/7429447)

Comment: I tried your solution to change the name to ´self.service_path´ but the same error occurs.

Comment: Changed the second line as well?

Comment: Yes absolutely. `self.driver = Firefox(service=self.service_path, options=self.opts)`

Comment: Are you executing the refactored code on the same machine?

Comment: I tested it on windows and it works. But the error occurs when testing on Mac.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241743/discussion-between-appcreator-and-undetected-selenium).

Comment: I think this is the answer. I upgraded the Selenium to 4. Now I get this error instead `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/geckodriver'`But I thinks this is because I am trying to get the geckodriver from the Windows virtual machine (Paralells) from iCloud

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error and fixed this problem by upgrading to Selenium 4.0

I am using Anaconda python.

To upgrade to Selenium 4.0 on Anaconda, run the following command;

```
$ conda install https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch::selenium
```

The following command also works fine.

```
$ conda install selenium --channel conda-forge/noarch
```

At this point of writing, you cannot upgrade Selenium using the normal conda command `conda update selenium`. Running this command will install selenium v3

[image]

You have to specify the installation on the noarch version which supports selenium v4.1

The link below teaches you how to do that.

[Specify platform during package install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288315/specify-platform-during-package-install)

Answer (score 0):

```py
self.driver = Firefox(service=self.service, options=self.opts)
```

The Firefox webdriver doesn't take a service keyword argument:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver

It would be helpful to see the older working version.

Comment: I added the working version

Comment: Are you using the same version of the selenium module in both cases?

Comment: What do the import statements look like in the working case?

Comment: It is the same import statements in both cases.

Comment: I tested it on windows and it works. But the error occurs when testing on Mac.

Comment: You probably have different selenium module versions between the two platforms... what does `pip list` (or whatever you're using for installing packages) say for the two of them?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see when you call

```
Firefox(service=self.service, options=self.opts)
```

it raises because Firefox class does not accept service kwarg

If you are trying to set up a Firefox web driver you can see [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Comment: Then why is my older code working that also has service kwarg?